# Maximum Contiguous Subsequence Sum with longest sequence?

Tags: java, data-structures

I know how to find a maximum, contiguous, subsequence sum; but sometimes there's more than one subsequence with maximum sum.  So, I need to find the index of those longest subsequences with the maximum sum.
The only thing I thought of is brute force.  What better options are there?

Here's a code I found on rosettacode which had the exact idea for my problem (but, sadly,  the only programming language I know is Java), but it is writen in REXX:

```
/*───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────*/
arg @                                  
say 'words='words(@) 'list='@          
say
sum=word(@,1)                          
w=words(@)                             
at=1                                   
L=0       

do j=1 for w;  f=word(@,j)

    do k=j to w; s=f

          do m=j+1 to k
          s=s+word(@,m)
          end   /*m*/

    _=k-j+1
    if (s==sum & _>L) | s>sum then do; sum=s; at=j; L=_; end
    end         /*k*/

end               /*j*/


seq=subword(@,at,L)
if seq=='' then seq="[NULL]"
sum=word(sum 0,1)
say 'sum='sum/1 "sequence="seq
/*───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────*/
```

Results:

```
input 1 2 3 4 -777 1 2 3 4 0 0 
output
words=12 list=1 2 3 4 0 -777 1 2 3 4 0 0

sum=10 sequence=1 2 3 4 0 0
```

Comment: That's not a question.  It's a problem description.  And probably homework.  __sigh__

Comment: I +1'd you for your ascii-art Owl face (it looks like an owl anyway.) I'm curious why `1 2 3 4 0 0` is a contiguous subsequence. Could you define contiguous subsequence for us?

Comment: @glowcoder:  Isn't `1 2 3 4 0 0` found consecutively within the list?  That would make it a contiguous subsequence.  What's confusing about it?

Comment: @mellamokb What's confusing is why `-777 1 2 3 4 0 0` isn't picked, since it's in list. What defines contiguous in this sense?

Comment: @glowcoder: Because the sum would be smaller...?  We want the largest contiguous subsequence that also has the **maximum** value.  That would reduce the sum from 10 to -767, so it's not a candidate.

Comment: @mellamokb Thanks - that's a definition that we can work with!

Answer (score 2):

If this is homework, I'd recommend you take a look at dynamic programming algorithms. In particular, you can simplify one of the steps of the Smith-Waterman local string alignment to do exactly what's needed here. The key is to read up on the idea of optimal substructure and ask yourself, is there some kind of subproblem involved which I can solve using only local information at each point in the sequence?

Comment: I'm not asking for my homework, just a help to learn,, especially the ideas behind the source code i'd given above..or anylinks (due hardly acsess academic literature )so i could learn more 'bout this problem..

it's called contiguous subseq. cuz its connected consecutively within the sequence.,,that's how i explained it,,since u've found that english isnt my native language,,^_",,
1 2 3 4 0 0 had the max sum than any subseq,,and had longer than just 1 2 3 4 or 1 2 3 4 0,,